# Changing Semicolon from Multi-Select Picklist values to a Comma in the same field

Tags: apex

I need answer for this issue in same field only.(not in another field). If we select any pick list fields,then only I must get exact output like  (Telangana; Andhra pradesh; Delhi) i must get(Telangana,Andhra pradesh, Delhi)

But, what ever the fields I selected, the result should  be come comma at end of the fields.(but not semi  column)

My image : [image]

Any ideas?

Comment: by default is come as semi colon separated only.. thats who it get stored in DB..  but if you want to change it.. you can replace it with comma or whatever symbol you can

Comment: Thanks@Sagar Hinsu How can we change or replace it to comma

Comment: what is your purpose for comma rather than semi colon?

Comment: As per as my client requirment is he want commas rather then semi columns

Comment: if you want to be replaced with comma you cant do that in the same field.you have to create a formula field and format to display the values with comma

Comment: I got your point i tried formula field and i got the output also but my client is asking to do only in the same field only....but not other any fields.....

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for is, at this time, impossible.

Multiselect picklist fields are both stored (in Salesforce) and displayed with semicolons.

About the only thing you can do here is to take the advice from the comments, and create a formula field and use `SUBSTITUTE()` to replace the semicolons.

You should go back to your client and explain that semicolons separating values for multiselect picklists is something that cannot be altered. It would also be good for you to figure out *the reason why your client wants this*.

Generally speaking, the role of the client involves communicating *what* they want, but not *how* to achieve it. If your client doesn't know how Salesforce works (which  does seem to be the case), then they'll have a very low chance of knowing *how* something can be (or needs to be) done.

As the Salesforce "expert" for your client, your job is to figure out the reasons behind client requests so you can deliver an appropriate solution. In this case, it could be that the client is trying to extract information from Salesforce and plug it into excel for reporting. You won't know unless you ask your client, and you won't be able to develop an appropriate solution if you don't know how it's going to be used.